# Video not playing in html

Tags: html, html5-video

The video will not play, could someone please look at my code please to check where I'm going wrong

```
        <p> 
    
    <object id="media1" height="200" type="video/mp4" width="200">
        <param name="filename" value="Womanbuyingphone" />
        <param name="uiMode" value="full" />
    </object> 
    </p>
    
    <p>
    <object id="media2" height="200" type="video/mp3" width="200">
        <param name="filename" value="Linkinpark.mp3" />
    </object>
    </p>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the `<video>` element? Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Your video file needs a file extension, is it an MP4 like maybe  `Womanbuyingphone.mp4`? See if the updated Answer below works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try HTML5 Audio and video Tag to display audio and vedio.

```
<video id="media1" width="400" height="200" controls>
  <source src="Womanbuyingphone.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<audio id="media2" height="200" width="200" controls>
  <source src="Linkinpark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```